# Refresh expired JWT token

Tags: jwt

this is my middleware in backend

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
const auth = req.get('Authorization');

if (!auth) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        "response": {
            "message": 'Not authorized user',
        }
    })
}

const token = auth.split(' ')[1];
let decode;
try {
    decode = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY)
} catch (err) {
    return res.status(401).json({
        "response": {
            "message": 'Invalid token access',
        }
    })
}

if (!decode) {
    return res.status(500).json({
        "response": {
            "message": 'Error token access',
        }
    })
}

let userId = decode.id;

User.findById(userId)
    .then(user => {
        req.user = user;
        next();
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(401).json({
            "response": {
                "message": `Error on authorization`,
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I need integration of auto refresh token on each call when expire, and how can do for resave in localstorage in my client side?

Have my front-end developed with vue and vuex. Use this `localStorage.setItem('access_token', token);` code for save in localstorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the logic that I did in my own web app

1. When user logs in you need to create access and refresh token
2. After you receive both tokens keep them in localStorage or wherever is safe
3. You need to create a refreshToken route(**/refresh-token**) to call when your access token expired
4. Define a middleware to check tokens and use it in secured routes
5. When you get an 401 error call **/refresh-token** route to refresh the token
   **config file**

```js
{
  "secret": "secret",
  "refreshTokenSecret": "refresh-secret",
  "port": 8080,
  "tokenLife": 900,
  "refreshTokenLife": 86400
}
```

**login route(app.js)**

```js
router.get('/login',(req, res) => {
 const postData = req.body;
 const user = {
     "email": postData.email,
     "name": postData.name
 }
 const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, { expiresIn: config.tokenLife})
 const refreshToken = jwt.sign(user, config.refreshTokenSecret, { expiresIn: 
 config.refreshTokenLife})
 const response = {
   "status": "Logged in",
   "token": token,
   "refreshToken": refreshToken,
 }
 tokenList[refreshToken] = response
 res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

**refresh token route(app.js)**

```js
router.post('/refresh-token', (req,res) => {
    const postData = req.body
    if((postData.refreshToken) && (postData.refreshToken in tokenList)) {
        const user = {
            "email": postData.email,
            "name": postData.name
        }
        const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, { expiresIn: config.tokenLife})
        const response = {
            "token": token,
        }
        // update the token in the list
        tokenList[postData.refreshToken].token = token
        res.status(200).json(response);        
    } else {
        res.status(404).send('Invalid request')
    }
})
```

**tokenMiddleware.js**

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const config = require('./config')

module.exports = (req,res,next) => {
  const token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token']
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(401).json({"error": true, "message": 'Unauthorized access.' });
        }
      req.decoded = decoded;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    return res.status(403).send({
        "error": true,
        "message": 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
}
```

**use middleware to protect routes**

```js
router.get('/secured-route', tokenMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
    res.send("secured");
});
```

Comment: this text _**When you get an 401 error call /refresh-token route to refresh the token**_ intend for client side?

Comment: Yes, from client when you call a secured api with access token and it gives you unauthorized error, you can refresh the access token by sending both access and refresh token to get a new access token and call the secured api again with new access token

Comment: If you want to use a library to handle auth with less code, you can take a look at  [passport.js library for express example](https://www.pveller.com/oauth2-with-passport-10-steps-recipe/)

Comment: @onuriltan I have two questions: 1.how to resend previous request after calling refresh token endpoint? 2. if there are multiple requests to be sent to back-end at one time, then all requests failed if token expired, thus how to prevent all these failed request send refresh token request?